# Теряется HttpContext.Current после await

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Есть сайт на ASP.NET MVC 5.

Я изменил одно из действий на асинхронное и заметил, что после await теряется контекст.

Т.е в `HttpContext.Current` содержится `null`.

Подскажите, я должен сам сохранять контекст или есть штатные методы?

Comment: Вот здесь что-то есть на тему https://stackoverflow.com/a/57908890/8324991

Comment: Вот здесь как-то подробнее и по сути https://stackoverflow.com/a/28433417/8324991